# Unable to create JFrame even i installed Windowbuilder in my Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, windowbuilder

I have already installed `Windowbuilder` in my eclipse IDE Mars it worked fine before, but after Eclipse latest changes i am unable to install `windowsbuilder` with the provided URL of specific  IDE `Windowbuilder`. later i figured out that we must install the `Windowbuilder` by downloading the `repository.zip` file. i have downloaded and installed it but still unable to create a `JFrame` in my Java Project. But what i am confused is i am able to paste a SWT/AWT code in a simple Java Class file and able to execute it.

have installed the repository .zip

[image]

No JFrame found after installation.
[image]

updated error
[image]

Answer (score 1):

GO this route as it has worked for me: Go to help menu in eclipse go to "About Eclipse" in the bottom left corner click on "Installation Details", click the "installed software" tab, search for window builder and click to delete all features for it. Restart Eclipse, then instead of installing window builder using the "install new software" menu in help, open eclipse market place, search for window builder and install it that way, when you get the options you want to install click on Swing that lets you create JFrames. If that does not work, download a new copy of eclipse and go back to the market place and install window builder again, its possible you have conflicting plugins in your installation. I was able to install it in 2018-09 just yesterday, if that still does not work please comment.

Comment: I did like you said but its giving me an error "The following solutions are not compatible with this version of eclipse". please check i have updated the post with screenshot

Comment: what version of eclipse are you using, i suggest going to eclipse.org click download get the installer install the flavor of eclipse you want to ensure you have the latest version, then go back to help -> market place and install window builder, if you get an error doing that paste the screnshot